# R: Using pkgload::load_all without testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I try to host an application on a connect server that needs to execute `pkgload::load_all` in order to make the package function available to the process.

However, even with `pkgload::load_all(helpers = FALSE, attach_testthat = FALSE)` the build processes of the application crashes because `testthat` needs to be installed on the system. I don't get it. In the official package documentation of `pkgload`, the `testthat` package is only under suggest, so it should not be required for running the functionality, especially when disabling the helpers.

I don't want to install testhat on my hosting machine for several reason, so I wonder if there is any other option here?

Comment: Hey, is it possible to install the package that contains the function you want to run on the connect server?